# How to change facebook profile picture and change its back on time with JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I seen this app from Facebook can change profile picture back on time after we change their profile.
https://www.facebook.com/gameface

Anyone can advise me? How to make likes this with JavaScript SDK.

Because after looking for document on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/
I don't found the parameter on Graph API look like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t.

It is not possible to change a user profile picture via API – at least not for common 3rd-party apps.

Whenever you’ve seen one of those “merge my cover photo with another picture/flag/logo to show support for cause x” apps/campaigns (that can do so automatically), or the temporary profile picture feature you meantioned – these are apps resp. functionality made directly by Facebook, or a partner company.

The most you can – or cloud, I don’t know if that is still possible – do, is let the user upload an image to their profile pictures album, and then (web/desktop only) redirect them to a specific URL, that brings up a page/dialog, that allows them to set that image as their new profile picture. (I don’t remember the specifics of that URL – if you’re interested in that possibility, research it, or try and figure it out via their UI in the browser.)

Comment: Thank you !! I will try your solution :)